# SVG <g> <path> Mac Chrome not displaying

Tags: html, css, svg

So I am using the following HTML code to display an SVG:-

```
<a href="<?php the_field('instagram_url', 'options'); ?>" target="_blank">                      
  <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       width="512.000000pt" height="512.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 512.000000 512.000000"
       preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,512.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
       fill="#000000" stroke="none">
      <path d="M1233 5105 c-607 -111 -1081 -572 -1210 -1175 -17 -80 -18 -167 -18
               -1370 0 -1195 1 -1291 18 -1368 127 -591 574 -1039 1167 -1168 80 -18 154 -19
               1370 -19 1199 0 1291 1 1368 18 590 127 1042 579 1169 1169 17 77 18 169 18
               1368 0 1204 -1 1290 -18 1370 -62 289 -201 544 -412 755 -217 217 -463 350
               -760 410 l-123 25 -1248 -1 c-986 -1 -1264 -4 -1321 -14z m2670 -417 c316 -87
               563 -289 706 -576 49 -96 86 -221 101 -334 8 -57 10 -457 8 -1273 l-3 -1190
               -27 -98 c-31 -112 -97 -257 -158 -346 -55 -83 -158 -190 -239 -252 -91 -69
               -266 -153 -386 -186 l-100 -28 -1245 0 -1245 0 -98 27 c-316 87 -563 289 -706
               576 -47 93 -85 218 -100 326 -15 107 -15 2345 0 2452 67 486 452 864 944 927
               17 3 575 4 1240 3 l1210 -1 98 -27z"/>
      <path d="M4078 4331 c-67 -22 -120 -79 -139 -153 -38 -140 107 -277 249 -237
               95 26 163 132 147 228 -8 50 -51 111 -98 140 -40 24 -118 35 -159 22z"/>
      <path d="M2325 3924 c-501 -87 -919 -451 -1080 -937 -46 -140 -65 -265 -65
               -427 0 -162 19 -287 65 -427 162 -488 583 -851 1089 -938 115 -19 337 -19 452
               0 580 100 1039 559 1139 1139 20 116 19 336 -1 457 -70 419 -351 802 -732 997
               -122 63 -275 115 -401 136 -117 20 -355 20 -466 0z m390 -399 c363 -59 654
               -304 772 -650 122 -359 22 -765 -253 -1026 -335 -316 -843 -356 -1229 -96
               -302 204 -465 576 -414 943 75 543 583 917 1124 829z"/>
    </g>
  </svg>                            
</a>
```

This is so I can use `fill: #<hex>;` to set the colour on hover states... Instead of image replacement.

This works fine in Mac Safari, Windows Safari, it just doesn't even display in Mac Safari, using `fill: #FFF;` I'm assuming is not working to change the SVG colour from black to white.

I created a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/silvawebdesigns/f93m025p/6/) which works as it's supposed to, but on the live site it doesn't display anything, it used to work fine so I'm not sure what's happened here...

When I inspect where the SVG should show, it just doesn't show any HTML code for the SVG icon above.

It's only in Mac Chrome, latest version...

Any ideas?

If you need any more information, just let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: Is it maybe a cache issue? What happens if you open the page in an incognito window? (I assume you mean “doesn’t even display the code in Mac [Chrome]”.)

Comment: @Ry- - Sorry my bad, it does show, I just don't think the fill: colour is working....

I can provide a link but I don't think would be useful for other users having the same problem in future...

Comment: Some recent bug perhaps? Try searching/reporting [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)